# Publish Laravel Project and Project Deployment on LAMP

Tags: php, git, apache, laravel, deployment

I am now developing a PHP website using Laravel 5 framework. I published the website through Git clone to the server. However, after visiting the URL, the website only shows its structures, which is shown as: http://mikemikezhu.me/laravel/laravel_trial/

The index.php in the public folder cannot be parsed, and only the folder structure is displayed. My server is running Centos 7 system. The web server is Apache and the PHP version is 5.4.16. I am wondering whether it is because the PHP version is too old to run the Laravel. Or is there any other ways to publish the website correctly? I am not going to use Forge and Envoyer bacause they are not free of charge.

Comment: are you able to see welcome page on this url http://mikemikezhu.me/laravel/laravel_trial/public  if yes you have to just point your host to this directory

Comment: error 500, you should `chmod -R 777 storage` and `chmod 775 -R vendor`

Comment: or `chown -R :www-data yourproject`. Don't worry about PHP version because Laravel 5.0 require PHP >= 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have the correct PHP version for your application with the command:

```
php -v
```

- If you are using Laravel 5.0 you need [PHP >= 5.4, PHP < 7](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0#server-requirements)
- If you are using Laravel 5.1 you need [PHP >= 5.5.9](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation)
- If you are using Laravel 5.2 you need [PHP >= 5.5.9](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#server-requirements)

If you are deploying the app with Git, check if the folder permissions are correct and compatible with the Apache user.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly make sure the whole directory structure including files is owned by the apache user - using the chown command.
2. you'll want to point your vhost to the public folder, not the project route
3. https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors shows you how to enable debug and logging - great for seeing why it might not be working
4. I'd update to at least PHP 5.6 as @amieiro mentions